# Booting Debian Buster Directly to Chromium Kiosk

Tags: chromium, boot, debian-buster

I have an embedded device similar to a Raspberry Pi.  It came installed with Debian Buster, slim, and xfce.  The requirement I have is to boot directly to Chromium in kiosk mode.  I have had limited success with the following:

1. Slim logs in as a named user and starts xfce.  Set Chromium as a startup application in xfce.  However xfce still comes up and displayed for a couple of seconds which is unacceptable.
2. Remove xfce, have slim login as a named user, and have my systemd startup script/unit start chromium.  Chromium came up but with a login screen displayed for a couple of seconds which is unacceptable.

I tried removing slim since it is not supported anymore.  I put the chromium start in .xinitrc and called startx from my systemd startup script/unit.  I see the screen rotate 90 degrees as per the xorg.conf file but Chromium does not come up.  An error displays when I run the command manually that says unable to open the X display.

My .xinitrc file is:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "`date` : Starting x server" >> /dev/console
startx & 

#clean the controller cache
echo "`date` : Clear Chromium Cache" >> /dev/console
rm -rf /home/user/Chromium/Default/Cache 

#start chromium
echo "`date` : Starting Chromium" >> /dev/console
exec su -l user -c "export DISPLAY=:0; chromium --app=http://127.0.0.1"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the issue may be with chromium.  Based on prints to the dev console I see the command to start Chromium coming immediately after the x server starts but the browser does not show up on the screen until about 10 seconds have elapsed.  I ran the command manually and saw some errors that I am trying to track down - export DISPLAY=:0; chromium --disable-gpu --app=http://127.0..0.1

Comment: edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
gpu_channel_manager.cc(459)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: Failed to create shared context for virtualization.
object_proxy.cc(632)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files

Comment: I was able to get rid of the xterm screen by changing the slim.conf to use .xinitrc to start chromium instead of my startup systemd script/unit.  There is still a 10 second delay from the start of chromium (blank screen) to the internal website showing.  Still having difficulties bringing this down.  It may not matter as much since I also have to wait for postgresql to come up for my backend code to be able to start.